# What do the four items of filevers/prodvers mean in file_version_info.txt?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm writing a `file_version_info.txt` for PyInstaller and I'm wondering what does the exactly mean about this four digits? Such as the last one is usually a date (maybe?).

```
# filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
# Set not needed items to zero 0.
filevers=(1, 9, 7, 30920),
prodvers=(1, 9, 7, 30920),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version info is specific to the Windows platform, filevers and prodvers
represent binary version numbers in the format
`<major>.<minor>.<patch>.<build>`. The last one is not a date rather a build or
revision number (which is why it's usually a much larger number).